# Table 'tableName' contains a constraint definition with column 'columnName' which is not in the table Java Derby

Tags: sql, derby

I am trying to run a SQL script to my database created on Java Derby:

```
    CREATE TABLE USUARIO (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    NOMBRES VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    APELLIDOS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONTRASEÑA VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CEDULA INTEGER,
    TELEFONO INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT ID_USUARIO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) -- Primary Key
);

CREATE TABLE ORGANIZACION (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, -- Id autonumérico
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ID_ORGANIZACION_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT ID_DIRECCION_ORG_FK FOREIGN KEY (DIRECCION_ORG) REFERENCES DIRECCION_ORG (ID),
    CONSTRAINT ID_TELEFONO_ORG_FK FOREIGN KEY (TELEFONO_ORG) REFERENCES TELEFONO_ORG (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TELEFONO_ORG (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, -- Id autonumérico
    TELEFONO INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ID_TELEFONO_ORG_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DIRECCION_ORG (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, -- Id autonumérico
    DIRECCION VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ID_DIRECCION_ORG_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    RUTA_IMAGEN VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CANTIDAD INTEGER,
    PRECIO INTEGER,
    COSTO INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT ID_PRODUCTO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID), -- Primary Key
    CONSTRAINT ID_ORGANIZACION_FK FOREIGN KEY (ORGANIZACION) REFERENCES ORGANIZACION (ID)
);
```

But I am getting this error:

> Table ORGANIZACION contains a constraint definition with column
>   DIRECCION_ORG which is not in the table.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Your `constraint` clause is looking in the `ORGANIZACION` table for a column called `DIRRECCTION_ORG`. You need to make the column in the table. I'd suggest naming it something else because it is the same name as another table in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making constraints to foreign keys but haven't actually created the columns to contain those keys yet. Make those columns and make the constraints point to them (instead of just using the table's name again). Shown below with `--` comments indicating where to add it.

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIO (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    NOMBRES VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    APELLIDOS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONTRASEÑA VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CEDULA INTEGER,
    TELEFONO INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT ID_USUARIO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) -- Primary Key
);

CREATE TABLE ORGANIZACION (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, -- Id autonumérico
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DIRECCION_ORG_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,   -- ADD THIS and change constraint FK name
    TELEFONO_ORG_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,   -- ADD THIS and change constraint FK name

    CONSTRAINT ID_ORGANIZACION_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT ID_DIRECCION_ORG_FK FOREIGN KEY (DIRECCION_ORG_ID) REFERENCES DIRECCION_ORG (ID),
    CONSTRAINT ID_TELEFONO_ORG_FK FOREIGN KEY (TELEFONO_ORG_ID) REFERENCES TELEFONO_ORG (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TELEFONO_ORG (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, -- Id autonumérico
    TELEFONO INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ID_TELEFONO_ORG_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DIRECCION_ORG (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, -- Id autonumérico
    DIRECCION VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ID_DIRECCION_ORG_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    RUTA_IMAGEN VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CANTIDAD INTEGER,
    PRECIO INTEGER,
    COSTO INTEGER,
    ORGANIZACION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, --ADD THIS and change constraint FK name

    CONSTRAINT ID_PRODUCTO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID), -- Primary Key
    CONSTRAINT ID_ORGANIZACION_FK FOREIGN KEY (ORGANIZACION_ID) REFERENCES ORGANIZACION (ID)
);
```

Comment: I tried that, i have changed the name of the constraints and created the columns in the table, but still having the same error :(. Even if i put the same code that you provided me

Comment: When you say you changed the constraint name, you mean you changed the `FOREGIN KEY (DIRRECCION_ORG)` to `(DIRRECCION_ORG_ID)` correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake was that i had to put the tables DIRECCION_ORG and TELEFONO_ORG above from ORGANIZACION and PRODUCTOS. Because the FK were created before the creations of the references. Thank you and problem solved!.

Answer (score 1):

Both the columns `DIRECCION_ORG` and `TELEFONO_ORG` are not defined in the table `ORGANIZACION`

The same problem occurs in the table `PRODUCTO` where the column `ORGANIZACION` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your CONSTRAINT clause.

The format of the FOREIGN KEY constraint is:

> > CONSTRAINT {constraint name} FOREIGN KEY ([This_table_column],...) REFERENCES [Other_table] ([Other_table_column], ...).

Read this: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html#rrefsqlj13590